# What to say in the following situation?

Tags: spoken-english

When we have to pay gratitude to one respectable person, we say "Thank you."

But if there are two or more persons then what to say?

As "Thanks to all of you" doesn't seem formal.

Any suggestions?

Comment: respectable person is not really right here.

Comment: "You" is the second person singular.  **"You" is also the second person plural.**

Answer (score 1):

Definition of Cambridge Dictionary of "you":

> used to refer to the person **or people** being spoken or written to

Remember, "you" is both a singular and plural pronoun. Therefore, no matter how large the audience is, you can simply say "thank **you**"

I personally believe that "thank you" is enough and there is no need for "thanks to all of you" (though it is grammatically correct). "Thank you all" is also possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could also say 'Thanks to each of you'. Or, to an audience, 'Thanks to each and every one of you' to individualize it further.